# jQuery get the height from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, height

I need to get the height from top of the page to current scrollbar position and place it to my link:

```
<a class="poplight" rel="popup_name" href="#?w=here comes the value"></a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the offset()

```
$('.poplight').offset().top
```

If you need to scroll to that position:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.poplight').offset().top
}, 400);
```

If you need the distance from the top of the window to the current position based on scroll:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Want to add that to the url:

```
$(".poplight").attr("href", "#" + $(window).scrollTop())
```

Comment: No, no. I have to put the height in px from top of the site to current view. For example, you scroll the site to the half, and I need to have the height from top to current view and put it to my link.

Comment: Yes! That's it. And now, how to put the dintance in px to my link?

Comment: it's not putting the value into my link.

Here's the site: http://daniel-koczula.pl/testowy/ I need (for example to the red bottom button) to put the distance from the top of the window to the current position based on scroll to link. When you hover the button you'll see http://daniel-koczula.pl/testowy/#?w=3200 and i need to put the value after w=